# HOW TO CREATE RECURSIVE FUNCTION IN POSTGREQL 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query, postgresql-9.6

I have a `menus` table and a `menu_headings` table. They looks like that:

`menus` table:

```
id | object_id | name         | menu_heading_id | price | parent_id |

3  | 45        | Chicken soup | 4               | 120   |     0     |
4  | 45        | Whiskey      | 5               | 65    |     0     |
5  | 45        | Jack Daniels | 5               | 100   |     4     |
```

`menu_headings` table:

```
id | object_id | name      |
4  | 45        | Hot meals |
5  | 45        | Drinks    |
```

I am new at postgresql and I want to write recursive function on my pgsql query.
I want to fetch data something like that:

```
-Hot meals
    +Chicken soup*

-Drinks
   -Whiskey
     -Jack Daniels
```

Pls help me to get this

Comment: [Edit] the question and include what you have done yourself so far and describe where the specific problems with that are.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: storing `0` in the `parent_id` column to indicate "no parent" is a bad idea because it means you did not create a proper foreign key for that column. You should store `null`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the needed data from a single query with a recursive CTE. The trick is keeping descending levels together. As a function then that query becomes the single item within a SQL function.  
As far as the formatting of your desired that is something best left to the application (In general that is always the best to formatting.) I would probably not even attempt it in SQL and will not do so here. You can try that as an exercise. But to aid in that I generated 2 additional columns. The first column (new_heading) is either null or contains a asterisk (*). An asterisk indicates this row introduces a heading line. The last column (hier_level) shows the level in the hierarchy for that row (note the Heading would be level 0) and can be used to determine the indentation you want.

```
create or replace function todays_menu()
  returns table (new_heading   text
                ,menu_heading  text
                ,menu_item     text
                ,price         numeric
                ,hier_level    integer
                )
language sql
as $$
   with recursive the_menu (menu_heading, menu_item, price,  item_id, heading_id, parent_id, mpath) as
        (select mh.name, m.name menu_item, m.price, m.id item_id, m.menu_heading_id, m.parent_id, array[m.id]  
           from menu m 
           join menu_headings mh on m.menu_heading_id = mh.id   
          where parent_id is null 
         union all
         select mh.name, m.name, m.price, m.id ,m.menu_heading_id, m.parent_id, array_append(tm.mpath, m.id)   
           from the_menu tm
           join menu m on  m.parent_id = tm.item_id
           join menu_headings mh on m.menu_heading_id = mh.id     
        )        
   select case when coalesce(lag(menu_heading) over( order by heading_id, mpath),'') <> menu_heading then '*' else null end  new_menu
        , menu_heading, menu_item, price, array_length(mpath,1) hier_level
     from  the_menu
    order by heading_id, mpath;
$$;    

-- test
select * from todays_menu();
```

In the function note the column mpath. This column builds an array of the menu ids. Since arrays can be sorted this is used to keep each chain in the tree in the proper relation to each other. Also it determines the the hier_level mentioned above.  
Note: The query itself can be extracted and run stand alone. Also it depends on following @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion to use null for no parent_id instead of 0. That should always be followed.